# Fatal error: call to undefined function imagecreatefromjpeg() centos

Tags: php, centos, gd

I tried everythung that I could find.

I installed complete gd and my php info shows this

```
GD Support  enabled
GD Version  bundled (2.1.0 compatible)
FreeType Support    enabled
FreeType Linkage    with freetype
FreeType Version    2.3.11
GIF Read Support    enabled
GIF Create Support  enabled
PNG Support enabled
libPNG Version  1.2.49
WBMP Support    enabled
XBM Support enabled
Directive   Local Value Master Value
gd.jpeg_ignore_warning  0   0
```

I also added these extensions in php ini file

```
extension=gd.so
extension=php_gd2.dll
```

Still its not working, I'm getting same error:

```
Fatal error: call to undefined function imagecreatefromjpeg()....
```

Comment: Did you restart apache after installing extensions (if you installed it additionally)?

Comment: what php version?

Comment: `php_gd2.dll` dll is for windows, are you using windows or centos ?

Comment: Yes, I have restarted the apache. PHP Version 5.6.26. I commented php_gd2.dll

Comment: @BenClayton Can you help with it plz

Answer (score 0):

Have you recompiled PHP with freetype lib? try to go to

`http://yourserver.com:2030/index.php?module=php_switch`